# Python and RegExp - search and match

Tags: python

Some file(file.dat)

```
#####Start####
sometext
sometext
From: email@address.net
some text
some text
####End#####
```

**1**

```
import re
for line in open('file.dat'):
    _mail=re.search(r"\w+@\w+\.\w{2,4}").group()
print(type(_mail))
```

**Out: 'NoneType'**

**2**

```
import re
for line in open('file.dat'):
    if(re.match(r"From:.*",line)):
        _mail=re.search(r"\w+@\w+\.\w{2,4}").group()
print _mail
```

**Out: email@address.net**

Explain me, please. Why can't I use first way?

Comment: Start by giving us the right code. re.search can't possibly work this way as it expects 2 arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first try will search the mail pattern in each line. The variable _mail will contain, at the end of the loop, the LAST result of re.search (well, the result of re.search on the last line in the file, to be more precise).

So your result will be overwritten.

If you want to use the first way, you have to add:

```
if _mail: break
```

To end the loop

Answer (score 2):

Because in the first case you are checking each line for the pattern. You successfully get it when you are at the "From:" line but your loop continues and does a match for the next line and overrides your _mail object with None as the pattern doesn't match on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet overwrites _mail, regardless of which line you're matching against. As a result, you only see the regex applied to the last line of your input, which does not return any results (hence the `None`).  The second only matches against the From line, which is probably what you want to happen. You could also use `.startswith('From:')` there instead.

Answer (score 0):

On the line `sometext`, your regex fails. That means that you don't get a match object but `None` as the result of `re.search()`. If you then try to call the `.group()` method, it fails (because `None` doesn't have one, of course). So you should have got an `AttributError` (but your code is syntactically invalid anyway, so it shouldn't have run at all.